# Parsing json from url : JSONExeption (file well structured)

Tags: java, json

i'm using a java function to extract a json file from URL and then applying a web scraping to get data.
the link of json data : https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json

```
 public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        String jsonText = rd.readLine();
        System.out.println(jsonText.toString());
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);

        return json;

    } finally { is.close(); }
}
```

and the function to extract data :

```
 public void setHistoriqueData() throws Exception {
    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json");
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json.getJSONArray("AFG").toString());
    int length = jsonArray.length() ;
    String key = null;
    String value = null;
    for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
        Set<String> keys = json.getJSONArray("AFG").getJSONObject(i).keySet();
        Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            key = it.next();
            value = json.getJSONArray("AFG").getJSONObject(i).get(key).toString();
            map.put(key, value);
            System.out.println(map.toString());
        }
```

i have a classic error `Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must end with '}' at 1 [character 2 line 1]`
but as we see the file is well structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON data you read includes linebreaks (absolutely legal), but since you read just one line in `String jsonText = rd.readLine();` and immedately parse it, this line does not contain a complete JSON object and the execption is thrown.

Comment: And what you suggest ?

Comment: Read the whole file before parsing anything.